# Symfony2 Doctrine OneToMany Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a big understanding problem with OneToMany Relationship - i searched a lot but that didnt help, maybe someone can help me with this.

I have a Event Entity with OneToMany Relation

```
<?php

namespace #\#\#;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Turmforum\BookingBundle\Entity\Contact;

/**
 * Event
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="events")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Event
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contact", mappedBy="event")
 */
protected $event_contacts;

/**
 *
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->contacts = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getContacts() {
    return $this->contacts;
}

public function addContact(Contact $contact) {
    $this->contacts[] = $contact;

    return $this;
}
```

And have a Contact Entity with ManyToOne Relation

```
<?php

namespace #\#\#;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Turmforum\BookingBundle\Entity\Event;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contacts")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Contact
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="event_contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $event;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEvent() {
    return $this->event;
}
```

When i try to save my event details over a form i get the error:

> Neither the property "event_id" nor one of the methods "getEventId()",
>   "eventId()", "isEventId()", "hasEventId()", "__get()" exist and have
>   public access in class "Turmforum\BookingBundle\Entity\Event".

What am i missing?

Comment: Show your form also how you are saving your information

Comment: does your `contacts` table have an `event_id` column? you may need to update your schema

Comment: Thanks M Khalid Junaid, only your question let me think that the problem may not caused by the relation. I was so forced that i dont understand the relations that i didnt recognized that the problem was just a naming fault in my form type. Sorry

Comment: With the ORM you don't reference the `event_id` you reference the `event` as, in the eyes of the ORM, the event_id doesn't exist.